# Items in more than one places (not cloned)

Tags: item-clones

We are using Sitecore 9.2 and SxA ...

I have the requirement for second level menu items to be based on the children of top level items. They don't want to select these second level items manually as pages are created / deleted regularly.

So I can get the children of the top level items. No problem. But they need certain second level items to appear in more than one menu ... Not sure how to do this as they would need to appear in two places in the tree and we don't want to clone items as these items can then be edited in more than one place.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can share content between (sxa) sites using delegated area's. https://doc.sitecore.com/users/sxa/19/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/share-content-as-a-delegated-area.html

Comment: That would seem to be a good option for this ... Can you put your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

**Option one: copy the item**

If you want the same item to appear in multiple places within content tree, you could copy the item. Copying an item will create a new item with the same content. You would be able to edit the same content in multiple places but the items are not linked together.

**Option two: clone the item**

Another option is to clone an item (as many times as you wish) to any location within the content tree. This is called: content sharing between (sxa) sites using delegated area's.

> If you edit a field in the original item and save it, SXA updates the field in all the cloned items in the delegated area. If you enable the use of the SXA delegated area when you clone items from a master site to a local site, you cannot change these items locally. This is because a clone is an item that is not just a copy of the original item, but one that inherits the field values from the original item. This can be convenient, for example, if you want to reuse blog posts from your master site and do not want to have to add every new blog post manually.

Content editors won't be able to edit a clone but will see a warning containing a link to the source item.

[image]

See the full documentation: https://doc.sitecore.com/users/sxa/19/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/share-content-as-a-delegated-area.html